# Modal View Popover: Always full screen?

Tags: xamarin.ios

I've created a view. and show from bottom with height 200

I'm using the following code to present it (in a touch event):

```
 var pvc = Storyboard.InstantiateViewController("demoStoryboard") as ModalViewController;

            pvc.View.Frame = new CGRect(0, this.View.Frame.Height - 200, this.View.Frame.Width, 200);
            pvc.ModalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationStyle.Custom;
            pvc.ModalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyle.CoverVertical;

            this.PresentViewController(pvc, true, null);
```

When it's presented, though, it always fills the screen, instead of having a height of just 200.

I've tried changing the ModalPresentationStyle property, but it makes no difference.

how can i fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Even you set the *Frame* for the *View* of **ModalViewController** as,

```
pvc.View.Frame = new CGRect(0, this.View.Frame.Height - 200, this.View.Frame.Width, 200);
```

Inside **ModalViewController**, between **ViewWillAppear** and **ViewDidAppear** methods, the *Frame* property value is changing. It's because **ViewWillLayoutSubviews** method is called in between **ViewWillAppear** and **ViewDidAppear** methods. This method, **ViewWillLayoutSubviews** is where the *Frame* property is actually been set. It sets the default value for the *Frame* property, that is the *full screen size*. So this is the method where you should set your custom *Frame* property value so that the default value is overridden.

That is, inside **ModalViewController**,

```
public override void ViewWillLayoutSubviews()
{
    base.ViewWillLayoutSubviews();
    View.Frame = new CGRect(0, View.Frame.Height - 200, View.Frame.Width, 200);
}
```

And you can avoid setting the *Frame* property value in the *parent view controller*. That is,

```
pvc.View.Frame = new CGRect(0, this.View.Frame.Height - 200, this.View.Frame.Width, 200);
```

can be removed.